# what is operater * really mean when use for list ？

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to achieve something like C's `structure`, so I predefine a list :

```
__list = [0] * 1001
```

everything works well.

but when the list getting complicated (a sample)：

```
__list = [{"name": '', "score": 0}] * 3

for item in __list:
    name, score = input("input name and score split with blank:\n").split()    # raw_input for python2
    item['name'] = name
    item['score'] = int(score)
print(__list)
```

and I input this:

```
Lily 23
Paul 12
James 28
```

out:

```
[{"name": "James", "score": 28}, {"name": "James", "score": 28}, {"name": "James", "score": 28}]
```

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
__list = [{"name": '', "score": 0}] * 3
```

This will create a list with three *references* to a dictionary. Modifying any one of them modifies them all because they all refer to the same data.

If you want the list to hold references to different dictionaries, you may perform "deep copies" of a reference dict by using a list comprehension, for example,

```
__list = [{"name": '', "score": 0} for i in xrange(3)]
```

Comment: At least in python3 you don't need the deepcopy with list comprehension. You can use `[{"name": "", "score": 0 } for i in range(3)]`

Comment: @syntonym Of course, thanks, that's also true in python2. I updated the post.